# Exclude a WordPress post from pre_get_posts if a field is null

Tags: pre-get-posts

I have an CPT archive page that I would like to exclude certain posts from if a field is null. The field I want to look for is `title_group` and I am already using a different meta_key to order the results with. I am not sure how to use a second key to exclude posts. Thanks for looking!

```
function set_posts_per_page_for_attorneys_cpt( $atty ) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $atty->is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive( 'attorneys' ) ) {
    $atty->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
    $atty->set( 'meta_key', 'last_name' );
    $atty->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
    $atty->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    $atty->set( 'facetwp', true);
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'set_posts_per_page_for_attorneys_cpt' );
```

Comment: Sounds like a case for [`meta_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters). If you follow [this link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) and scroll down to `Multiple Custom Field Handling` you can see some examples.

Comment: Thanks – that got me in the right direction. Had to do a little more digging to resolve it fully. I've posted the answer for others to see.

Answer (score 0):

@Howdy_McGee – Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Below is the code I used. By the way, I know that the FacetWP plugin can be a little particular with queries. In case anyone is wondering, this works with it.

```
function set_posts_per_page_for_attorneys_cpt( $atty ) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $atty->is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive( 'attorneys' ) ) {

  $meta_query = array(array(
    'key'=>'last_name',
  ));

  $meta_query = $atty->get('meta_query');

  //filter out people without a particular key
  $meta_query = array(array(
    'key'=>'title_group',
    'value'=>'',
    'compare'=>'!=',
  ));

  //update the query
  $atty->set( 'orderby', $meta_key);
  $atty->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
  $atty->set( 'meta_query',$meta_query );
  $atty->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
  $atty->set( 'facetwp', true);
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'set_posts_per_page_for_attorneys_cpt' );
```

Comment: While this is working, I also need the posts to sort ASC by 'last_name'. I think I have overlapping meta_querys, but not sure how to resolve it...

Comment: Actually, I need to sort by two meta keys: 'last_name', then 'first_name'…